# Adjusting overflow of a LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a simple LinearLayout, within a RelativeLayout, that adds custom child views dynamically.

```
 <RelativeLayout        
    android:id="@+id/chart_main_panel"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/chart_right_panel" >

    ...

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/label_xAxis"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/chart_frag_time_height"
        android:layout_above="@id/volume_lay"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/chart_right_padding"         
        android:clipChildren="true"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
    </LinearLayout>

    ...

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here are the attributes for the custom child views that extend TextView. (The width and text are changed before it's added to the LinearLayout.)

```
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"    
    android:paddingTop="3dip"
    android:gravity="center" 
    android:maxLines="1"      
    android:textSize="@dimen/axis_text_size">
```

When I shrink the layout horizontally I'd like for the child views to remain in
the layout but 'slide' off the left side of the layout, being clipped at it's left edge (like overflow:hidden in css,) with the views to the right maintaining their size and relative position to each other and the layout. Currently the opposite is happening and I can't find a simple way to adjust this behavior.

*I have a picture of what's happening but don't have enough rep to post - sorry.

Answer (score 0):

After fruitlessly searching hither and yon for a simple way to do this, I'm resigned to the following:

Extend a HorizontalScrollView and override its onLayout() method:

```
class HideHorizontalLeftOverflowWrapper extends HorizontalScrollView 
{
    ... 

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b)
    {
        super.onLayout(changed,l, t, r, b);
        View wrappedView = super.getChildAt(0);
        if( wrappedView != null)
            super.scrollTo(wrappedView.getWidth(), 0);
    }
}
```

Wrap the LinearLayout with it:

```
<com...HideHorizontalLeftOverflowWrapper
    android:id="@+id/ofwrap_xAxis"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"     
    android:focusable="false"
    android:measureAllChildren="true"
    android:scrollbars="none" >    
     <LinearLayout
         android:id="@+id/label_xAxis"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="@dimen/chart_frag_time_height"  
         android:layout_gravity="right"          
         android:paddingRight="@dimen/chart_right_padding"
         android:orientation="horizontal"            
         android:clipChildren="true"
         android:gravity="right" >
     </LinearLayout>
</com...HideHorizontalLeftOverflowWrapper>
```